# How to add keys and values to a Hashmap while getting 'cannot resolve put symbol' error

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am working with [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) 1.4.1. I had just created a Hashmap and was following a tutorial (in Java) on how to populate and manipulate it.

However, I get a 'cannot resolve symbol put' error and the "put" command is in red.

The image I added shows the auto complete snapshot and although *java.util.HashMap* is imported, there isn't any "put" command that is available in autocomplete. The available commands also are showing in red. I tried to use them instead of the "put" command. I keep having this type of problem all along. How can I fix it?

[image]

```
import java.util.HashMap;

HashMap<String, String> pozisyon = new HashMap<String, String>();
pozisyon.put("SKale", "a8");
```

Comment: What does it mean 'pozisyon.put("SKale", "a8");][1]][1]' ?

Comment: They came to my question out of nowhere, they don't exist. Regards and Thank you

Comment: pozisyon the name of the HashMap put is the command and ("SKale" (key) and"a8" is value)...

Comment: Now, please make sure you have 'put' word between dot and left parenthesis.

Comment: Dear friend I just checked that Hashmap works under MainActivity but does not work (at least in my Studio) under Class formation. I want to use the Hashmap in a class. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot add elements in HashMap fields outside of methods. Things like this won’t work:

```
public class Class {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("one", "two");
}
```

If you want to achieve that, put it in the constructors, like so:

```
public class Class {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Class() {
        hashMap.put("one", "two");
    }
}
```

Another way you can do it is in a `static` block.

Comment: Hello, It works in the Mainactiviity as I just checked but does not work under  a Class formation. Is there anyway to help that? Can you check and  tell me if it works under a Class formation on your Studio??

Comment: @AzizS.Kural What do you mean by "under a Class formation"?

Comment: public class pozisyonKlasi { } This the Class that I created the Hashmap in. It doesnot work here. The problem!!

Comment: @AzizS.Kural Check EDIT1.

Comment: Dear Kanev Thank you!! I did the same mistake a few days ago and I thought that I learned from it. But still, better late than never. Thank you again...:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are wishing to put a value to a HashMap at the same time you initialize it. I will suggest you this "**magic**" Java syntax:

Try this:

```
 public class ClassName {
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("one", "two");
            put("two", "three");
        }
    };
    /*
        Other code and constructor can go here.
        ....
        ....
     */
}
```

Indeed, from Java anywhere even on a non-function code section, you can immediately call the object instance function and properties by following the pattern shown above;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Class {
    HashMap arrayList1 = new HashMap<>();;
    arrayList1.put("32", "Bangalore");
    arrayList1.put("32", "India");
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62015655/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).