# how to change the name of array in android script

Tags: java, android, arrays

i have arrays   say for ex

```
int img1[] = {R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,....}
int img2[] = {R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,....}
int img3[] = {R.drawable.c1,R.drawable.c2,....}
```

I want to define a varibale  for ex imgn 
 where when on some condition it has to select the different array 
imgn= img1 or imgn= img2 etc

```
if (rnd.nextInt(4) == 1) ( 
 imgn[rnd.nextInt(3)]);
```

where rnd is defined as Random

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)**

```
HashMap<String,int[]> arraynames = new HashMap<String,int[]>();
arraynames.put("img1", new int[]{R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,....});
int[]arr=arraynames.get("img"+rnd.nextInt(3));
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/NfjdCI)**</kbd>

Comment: do we need to import any thing ? because it is not finding  put fucntion  in the arraynames.put("img1", new int[]{R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,....}); iam using android.

Comment: we need to add values in constructor as suggested in [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158839/how-to-add-keys-and-values-to-a-hashmap-while-getting-cannot-resolve-put-symbol) thanks again